# IsDlg=1 causes no content to be displayed in dialog

Tags: 2013, css, modal-dialog

We are having a problem that has apparently been an issue for a while on all of our SP 2013 sites. Any dialog marked with `IsDlg=1` shows no content at all whatsoever. Meaning a thin white dialog is displayed. No content. No nothing. If I inspect the `iframe` using dev tools and remove the `IsDlg=1`, the full page displays in the dialog (ribbon and all).
[image]

Clearly a masterpage or some CSS has been messed with at some point in time but I cannot figure it out. I have tried resetting all masterpages but this has had no impact. If someone would have suggestions as to what I should be looking at, I would be very thankful.

EDIT:
Some additional info that is important. The content isn't even rendering. It's not that the HTML is being hidden. If I inspect the content, this is quite literally all there is

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX ">
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
           var gearPage = document.getElementById('GearPage');
           if(null != gearPage)
           {
               gearPage.parentNode.removeChild(gearPage);
               document.title = "Error";
           }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

From the ULS
`Error=Cannot make a cache safe URL for "styles/dlgframe.css",`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the `styles` folder in `_Layouts` was deleted. I do not believe I have a way to replace it. I guess I will need to install a dummy farm.

Comment: Try adding a new server to the farm, the layouts folder should be recreated then you can copy it to the other server. This way you can ensure that, if you have some custom solution placing files in the _layouts folder, they will be included.

Answer (score 0):

Before you build a new farm... Is the folder in the Windows recycle bin? Do you have any backups of the server? If it is a VM, can you revert from a snapshot? (Maybe copy it first and then revert.) Do you know someone else with a same version farm?

Do a search for "styles" and see if the folder got moved. (Accidental drag and drop?)